# Exporting a Jasper report to PDF output stream in web application

Tags: java, spring-boot, stream, jasper-reports

I'm working on a website, and it's supposed to generate reports.
So far I've got this code that exports the report to a PDF output stream, but I'd like to know how to return the PDF to the user or how would I go about viewing it to see if it's working.

```
    InputStream template = 
    getClass().getResourceAsStream(invoice_template_path);

    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(template);

    Map<String,Object> param = parameters(reservation);

    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, param);

    File pdf = File.createTempFile("output","pdf");
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print,new FileOutputStream(pdf));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JRPdfExporter and then pass your JasperPrint variable to the setExporterInput. the bellow code gives more details :

```
@GetMapping( produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getReport( ) throws Exception {
        /*
         here  you prepare your: JasperPrint print
       */

        //initiate exporter
        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(pdfOutputStream));

        SimplePdfReportConfiguration reportConfig = new SimplePdfReportConfiguration();
        reportConfig.setSizePageToContent(true);
        reportConfig.setForceLineBreakPolicy(false); 
      
            exporter.exportReport();
            res= pdfOutputStream.toByteArray();
   
        var headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename= filename.pdf");
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                .body(res);
    }
```

You probably had your answer already but this may help someone else...